# Is it possible to let webinator use the instance of selenium that was already created? C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I was wondering if it was possible to let Webinator use the browser window that i have already opened using selenium. Because now I need to create a new instance(config) and this just opens another browser window.

I think my code will do more explaining.

```
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(d => { return d.FindElement(By.Id("mainContentPlaceholder_Wizard1_ButtonCSV")).Displayed; });
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainContentPlaceholder_Wizard1_ButtonCSV")).Click();
        var config = new Config
        {
            LogScreenshots = true,
            LogLevel = Config.AvailableLogLevels.Verbose,
            BaseUrl = driver.Url,
            Browser = Config.AvailableBrowsers.FirefoxPlugins,
            Framework = Config.AvailableFrameworks.WebDriver,

        };
        // new instance so new browser window opens 
        var web = WebManagerFactory.CreateInstance(config);
        var fileUpload = LocateBy.Attributes(ByAttribute.Name("ctl00$mainContentPlaceholder$Wizard1$AsyncFileUploadCsv$ctl02"));

        web.Click(fileUpload, WaitUntil.DialogAppears("File Upload"));
        web.Dialog.SelectFiles(Comparison.Contains, "File Upload", @"C:\Users\bram\Desktop", "test2.csv");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

It is one of the oldest and most-asked for issues raised against Selenium project:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18